# Some library similar to Lottie Animations

Tags: android, lottie

Apparently Lottie Animations is only compatible with AndroidX

I was able to compile with version 2.1 but the application crashes when opening
`My gradle file`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.anim"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29 
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    implentation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    implentation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.+'
    implentation 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
 
   implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:1.5.0"
    
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

App crashes, animation similar

Comment: Can you share the crash report? You can get more support.